# deploying axis2 on jetty

Tags: jetty, apache-axis, war

Please help me with deploying axis2 on jetty. I am able to deploy the axis2 war file but I actually need to deploy axis2 as exploded war file so that I can use hot deployment feature of axis2.

Please tell the process or point me to an article on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Took the binary distribution and ran the ant script that comes with it.

Running the Ant script gave me a war file.

I exploded the war file using jar xvf and then placed all the content got by exploding th war file into the webapps directory of jetty.

It works like a charm...